# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in... on line 43

Tags: php

as in title, i got this error, my code below:

```
    require_once('../connect.php');

$id = $_GET["id"];
if(!empty($id)) {

$sql = "SELECT FROM predictions WHERE id=".$id;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo '
    <form action="edit2.php" method="POST">
        Teams:<br />
        <input type="text" name="teams" value="'.$row["teams"].'" required><br />
        Date:<br />
        <input type="text" name="date" value="'.$row["date_match"].'" required><br />
        Prediction:<br />
        <input type="text" name="prediction" value="'.$row["prediction"].'" required><br />
        Risk:<br />
        <input type="text" name="risk" value="'.$row["risk"].'" required><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="edit">
    </form>
    ';
}
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO predictions (teams, date_match, prediction, risk) VALUES ('".$_POST["teams"]."', '".$_POST["date"]."', '".$_POST["prediction"]."', '".$_POST["risk"]."',)";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        header("location: ../../index.php");
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}

$conn->close();
```

what is wrong here?
...................................................................................................................

Comment: sry for that dots but SOF didnt let me post without this

Comment: Is this your full code? Because I don't see closing for `if (!empty($id)) {`

Comment: oh rly... i didnt close this, haha, thank you :D

Comment: that's when a code editor with tag/brace/bracket matching comes in handy ;-)

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).